# Cannot run PhoneGap helloworld in Ripple

Tags: android, cordova, ripple

I have just downloaded "PhoneGap-start" source, which is like a hello world that one can use to develop with PhoneGap.

Then I installed Ripple for google chorome to debug my app.

But there is the problem, when I start this hello world app it just shows me "connecting to device" and that's it.

I am googling that problem for good 6 hours, but non of the suggestions helped so far...

Comment: Which version of PG are you using? Try to use PG 2.5 (I know this sucks) to make sure it is not a compatibility issue. I think they have a bug regarding the usuability of ripple and the newer version of PG.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm having the same problem and I just figured it out..

Click on the ripple icon in the top right then manage

After that check the checkbox that reads allow access to files..

refresh and it should work